Is this approach effective at building a credit record?
This question is aimed at the USA situation.
If you are new to the USA and have no credit record, Can you apply for credit cards and then make debt just to pay it off the next month? I fundamentally dislike being in debt, but I would still like to buy a house one day.
So, completely living within your means and just buying things on your credit card and then paying it off next payday. Does this prove to credit providers that you are reliable or do they not like the fact that you are using credit but not paying any real interest on the card?
The idea would then be if I rinse and repeat this for a certain amount of time and then I would eventually have a nominal debit balance on the credit cards. I'm unsure if having a debit balance on a credit card is good for your rating though.

I added the US tag because credit scores work differently around the world.

You say "debit balance" but do you mean "overpayment"?  Credit cards aren't designed for storing money, the bank (most credit card issuers are banks) will usually return the excess funds after a couple months.  Also, they call it a "credit balance" if the bank owes you money.

@BenVoigt Ok, so keeping some money of your own on a credit card is not a thing in the USA. Was there not a time you could do that to show you are responsible with money?

@NeilMeyer: For the big loans (mortgage for example), they'll ask for history of deposit accounts as well as the credit reports.  And in order for people who are horrible credit risk to be able to have a credit card, there are secured cards, which are paired with a deposit account and allow spending up to what's been deposited (which is then frozen as collateral).  But that is represented as two separate accounts, not a positive balance in the credit card account.  And the cardholder will only improve their credit score if they make payments (vs having the bank offset the collateral account)


Is this approach effective at building a credit record?

Yes. I can tell you that without theorizing, because this is literally what I and many people I know did as immigrants. Open credit cards (easier for me as a student at the time); even if low-limit and high-interest. Make purchases, that you can afford immediately, only and pay off the card the month you get the bill.
My credit rose rapidly and was pretty good ever since.

Does this prove to credit providers that you are reliable or do they not like the fact that you are using credit but not paying any real interest on the card?

Credit providers don't see that you paid off balances same month. They just see the credit rating from credit rating agency. And credit rating agency itself doesn't give a hoot that your repaying same month reduces interest income credit card companies might otherwise earn.
So yes, if a credit card company could do so, they might prefer a customer who pays only minimum required portion every month (as a better source of income). But they don't have that option as they don't have access to this data. And the people who DO have access (credit bureau), don't care as they aren't getting extra money off your interest.

Credit providers can see the details of what goes into your credit score, if they pay a higher charge to the agency. Credit card providers also make money off purchases, via merchant fees, not just from interest. You have a good score because it has been profitable to loan you money


do they not like the fact that you are using credit but not paying any real interest on the card?

The scoring companies do not care whether you pay interest or not. It's a measure of how reliably you pay off debt make monthly payments. Carrying a balance and paying interest will actually hurt your score if you use too much available credit. Use as little as possible and make certain you pay it off every month.
And note that it is possible to buy a house with an immature credit history. You might just have to put more money down (which is also a wise move) and shop around more at local banks since the big-box banks will just use their rigid computer formulas that don't take nuance into consideration enough. They're just loan factories at this point - churning out as many loans as they can to sell them to other banks to resell them as "mortgage bonds".

Some scoring models, particularly mortgage variants, do consider whether you have had an installment loan, like a car loan. ("Lack of recent installment loan information") Revolving credit has latitude to defer payments, an installment loan is more rigid.

In the UK it seems that not using a credit card you have, or using less than 1% of your credit limit, each month, may be unhelpful.

Fundamentally, you must understand that a credit score is how likely you are to pay your bills.  The details about how it is calculated has changed over time and I would be cautious about sites that claim methods of credit hacking.  Also a credit score is no indication of wealth.  If you have 10 million sitting in an investment account, that will not change your credit score one bit.
For myself, I found the best way to keep my credit score high is to be out of debt.  Having no mortgage, or car payments often has my score in the 800s, 850 is the max and the highest I got was around 825.
Now my daughter got married last year and I had a credit card offer for interest free for a decent amount of time.  I applied, and put up to the max of the interest free offer on the card.  Even though I pay the payment on time and there is no interest charge, because I am carrying a balance my score has gone down.  I hover between 775 and 800.
So if I was you I would open whatever credit card I could.  It is likely to have a low credit limit.  I would put some of my expenses on it every month and pay it off, in full, every month.  You don't want to be hit with a finance charge as it will likely be high, and it does nothing to build your credit.
After a few months I would ask to have the credit limit increased.
Doing this will build your credit about as fast as one could hope.

I'm not from the US, so please excuse the naive question: does paying rent and utilities on time also help with a credit record?

No. Paying rent and utilities generally does not get reported to credit agencies. It has no positive impact.

@MatthieuM. Not by default. However, there's some services, including those run by credit bureaus, that let you add rent and utility bills to your file. The newest credit scoring algorithms take those into account, particularly when existing information is lacking.

While paying rent and utilties on time does not normally help with a credit record, failure to pay rent and utilties on time may hurt your credit record.  Typically, unpaid bills will eventually go to a debt collector, who will then report you to the credit reporting agencies (they are legally required to warn you).

Card providers are fine with people who pay off the whole balance every month. They don't just make money from you paying interest, every merchant pays them a fee when settling the purchases.
Even if you could go from having a "good" credit score to having a "great" credit score by paying interest on CC debt, for it to be worth it, you have to be getting a cheaper loan in the future that makes up for more than the extra interest.
For a mortgage, it's generally much more important to have a large down payment than to have a "great" credit score.

If buying in the us, you definitely want enough of a down payment to avoid needing mortgage insurance, if at all possible. Usually, that means at least 20% down.

There used to be claims that credit cards like to see you at least once take out a larger amount of money and then pay it back slowly, to show that you were able to maintain a budget over a longer period of time.
I haven't heard that recently, so I suspect it is no longer true, if it ever was.
Essentially, if you borrow responsibly, and pay on time, and have a decent income source and/or savings, you will have a good credit rating.  Focus on those, and the rating will take care of itself.

A credit score is a reflection of how you have managed your budget transactions - positively and negatively - over time.
